# Can't boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Qualcomm wireless adapter enabled

Tags: boot, wireless, atheros

Good afternoon,

I have a Dell G3 3590 laptop with a Qualcomm/Atheros QCA9377 card that I wanted to do a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 on. I created a Live USB stick, and when I tried to boot from the USB stick, the boot process was hanging right around working with RFKill. Upon doing some research, I thought it might have to do with the wireless card. To make matters simpler, I just went into the BIOS and disabled the wireless card and switch. Doing that allowed me to boot into the USB stick and install Ubuntu, and I have internet connection over Ethernet, however every time I turn the wireless card back on and boot, it hangs again. Any advice would be helpful, as I am well and truly stumped. I've tried to do an apt-get upgrade, and the ath10k firmware is in /lib/firmware.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
I was able to get some more information. It appears that the issue may be due to the wireless card going unclaimed in the boot process. I’m assuming this is a driver issue, but I can’t seem to figure out where or how to install the driver via command line. Still working on it.